# MVC persistent cookie timeout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC forms authentication and to create and set a persistent cookie like below.

Web Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="70"/>
</authentication>
```

Account Controller (fyi createPersistentCookie always = True)

```
public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);

    }
```

For some reason if I reduce the timeout to below 64 my website times out after a roughly 40 - 60 seconds but if I set the time out to over 64 it works fine up to the timeout time in minutes. Would anyone have a idea why this could be happening?

Its driving me mental! Seems to only happen on a Asus Transformer, Android 3.2!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved itself after a few hours, have not been able to replicate. At this point I have assumed it was caused by some freak network or server issue. Has not reoccurred to date but it still mystify's me!